C++20 and newer - what's the best way to implement an "enum with more functionality"?
I've seen scores of threads over the years on how you could wrap an enum or template a class with the enum to add addtional functionality.
Consider the use case. I have an enum. I want to be able to create an object of a class around the enum class so that I can

convert to string
return value specific info

A simple way to do this is

enum class color : uint16_t {
unknown = 0,
red,
green,
blue,
};

class colorClass {
public:
colorClass(){ val = color::unknown; }
colorClass(color v)
 :val(v)
{}

//copy, move, assignment ctors section

bool isRed(){ return val == color::red; }
// more such functions

std::string toString() {
using enum color;
switch (val) {
  case red : return "red";
  case blue: return "blue";
  case green: return "green";
  case unknown: [[fallthrough]];
  default: return "unknown";
}
}

private:
 color val;
};


This works just fine. Now if I want to restrict this class some more I can use templating and concepts
enum class color : uint16_t {
unknown = 0
red,
green,
blue,
};


template<typename E>
concept ValidColor = std::is_enum_v<E>;

template<ValidColor E>
class colorClass {
// Pretty much the same implementation?
}; 

My memory's a little fuzzy but I think I've seen some clever implementations for toString using underlying type. I'm not looking to use any 3rd party libs.
Do I have the "modern" way right? Apart from enforcing the usage of the enum does the addition of templating provide any benefits?
Edit: I'm not asking just about reflection (and thanks for all the answers in that direction) but how C++20 and C++23 can enhance this "enum with a few tricks" class

There isn't a way to get the compiler to map the enum names to strings.  There are some reflection libraries out there that will help you do that.  Maybe C++26 will get reflection and the this could be done natively.

If your new code isn't compiling you should include a [mre] of it with the full compiler error message.

You can assign enum names and strings without repeating them using X Macros, but this is certainly not a modern way - it works even in pure C.

In your examples, all methods of colorClass are private and the toString method does not take zero arguments.

Download Magic Enum from github. Problem solved. (Unless your problem is absolute portability to every conforming compiler imaginable, that is).

Definitely read P2996: reflection for C++26 to see what you can expect in future and ensure that what you're doing now isn't too far removed from the interface you'll provide when C++ has static reflection of this kind.

@NathanOliver I fixed the code, thanks for the input

Despite the fact that the year is 2024 and I am using C++20, I still find myself using X macros for this as I have yet to find a better (non-external-library) solution:
#define DEFINE_ENUM_VAL(class_name, name) name,
#define DEFINE_ENUM_STR_CONVERSION(class_name, name) case class_name::name: return #name;

#define FOR_EACH_FOOBAR(DO) \
    DO(FooBar, ONE) \
    DO(FooBar, TWO) \
    DO(FooBar, THREE)

enum class FooBar
{
    FOR_EACH_FOOBAR(DEFINE_ENUM_VAL)
};

inline auto to_string(FooBar val) -> std::string
{
    switch (val) {
        FOR_EACH_FOOBAR(DEFINE_ENUM_STR_CONVERSION)
    }
    std::unreachable();
}

#undef FOR_EACH_FOOBAR

#undef DEFINE_ENUM_STR_CONVERSION
#undef DEFINE_ENUM_VAL

This is fairly easy to extend for any behaviors that can be derived from the enum type name and value identifiers.  However, a lot of the surrounding boilerplate will have to be repeated for every enum type that you want to support (though I bet this could be genericized a bit further if you wanted to avoid that, at the cost of relying even more on preprocessor magic).

In particular, short of reflection there is no way to avoid (wordy and error-prone) repetition of names for producing strings from identifiers, except using the preprocessor.

There's a working trick for cases with the maximum enumeration value of 0x8000 or so(the ICE limit for std::make_index_sequence). Then you can map strings to values using an array filled with std::source_location elements. Then you need to trim the strings from platform dependent name mangling:
template<typename enm>
requires std::is_enum_v<enm>
constexpr std::string_view enum_raw_name()
{return std::source_location::current().function_name();};

constexpr std::string_view enum_demangle_trim(std::string_view);//has platform specific implementation 

template<typename enm>
requires std::is_enum_v<enm>
constexpr std::pair enum_bounds{ 
    std::to_underlying(enm{}),
    std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_t<enm>>::max()
};

template<typename enm>
requires std::is_enum_v<enm>
constexpr std::string_view enum_value_name(enm const e, std::underlying_type_t<enm> u = {}) {
     using int_t = decltype(u);
     constexpr auto bounds  = enum_bounds<enm>;
     auto constexpr range = std::min(0x8000uz,std::size_t{bounds.second}-bounds.first);
     static auto constexpr map = []<std::size_t ... i>(std::index_sequence<i ...>){
            return std::array{ 
                   enum_demangle_trim(enum_raw_name<static_cast<enm>(int_t{i} + bounds.first)>())
            ..., "out of range"};
     }(std::make_index_sequence<range>{});
     return map[min(std::size_t{int_t{e}}-bounds.first, range)];
};

The limitations of above implementation are the maximum value of enumeration type and negative enumeration values - which are considered out of bounds. Meta programming can enable negative values as well; The variable template enum_bounds needs to be explicitly specialized.
The other pain point is the platform dependent implementation of enum_demangle_trim- which is supposed to shrink the underlying string from both sides to retrieve the enum names.

With C++20 (not 23), it's possible to convert small enum to string optimally like this:
// Force compile time storage of the enumeration's string value
template <auto str> struct Wrapper { static constexpr auto v = str; };

// Dumb find function for G++ pretty function parsing
constexpr const char * find(const char * str, char l, std::size_t off = 0, char avoid = 0)
{
    std::size_t p = 0; for(; str[p] && str[p] != l; p++) 
        if (str[p] == avoid) return "";
    return &str[p+off];
}

// Create a compile time char array containing the string for the given enumeration value, based on template function name 
template<typename enm, auto $> // The $ here is very important since it's search for in the function name
requires std::is_enum_v<enm>
constexpr auto enum_value_name_impl()
{ 
    constexpr const char * str = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; //std::source_location::current().function_name(); doesn't work, it doesn't contain the value
    constexpr const char * p = find(str, '$');
    constexpr const char * n = find(p, ':', 2, ']');
    if (*n == 0) return "";
    constexpr const char * e = *n == 0 ? n : find(n, ']');
    constexpr auto range = e - n;
    constexpr auto map = [&n]<std::size_t ... i>(std::index_sequence<i ...>){
        return std::array<char, range + 1>{*(n+i) ...};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<range>{}); // Strange syntax to construct a std::array from a const char * size limited array
    return &Wrapper<map>::v[0]; // Convert the char array above to a static string
}

template<typename enm>
requires std::is_enum_v<enm>
constexpr const char* enum_value_name(enm const e, std::underlying_type_t<enm> u = {}) {
     auto constexpr range = std::size_t{128};
     constexpr auto map = []<std::size_t ... i>(std::index_sequence<i ...>){
            return std::array<const char*, range+1>{ 
                   enum_value_name_impl<enm, enm{i}>()
            ...};
     }(std::make_index_sequence<range>{});
     return map[std::min(static_cast<std::size_t>(e), range)];
};


The code is inspired from the answer above, but the previous answer doesn't work (too many errors to fix it).
Example usage here.
This code is optimal, it compiles to this:
.LC0:
        .string "%s %s %s %s %s?"
main:
        push    rax
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:Wrapper<std::array<char, 5ul>{char [5]{(char)84, (char)104, (char)105, (char)115}}>::v
        mov     r9d, OFFSET FLAT:Wrapper<std::array<char, 5ul>{char [5]{(char)76, (char)105, (char)102, (char)101}}>::v
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     r8d, OFFSET FLAT:Wrapper<std::array<char, 5ul>{char [5]{(char)82, (char)101, (char)97, (char)108}}>::v
        mov     ecx, OFFSET FLAT:Wrapper<std::array<char, 2ul>{char [2]{(char)65}}>::v
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:Wrapper<std::array<char, 3ul>{char [3]{(char)73, (char)115}}>::v
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rdx
        ret
Wrapper<std::array<char, 5ul>{char [5]{(char)76, (char)105, (char)102, (char)101}}>::v:
        .string "Life"
Wrapper<std::array<char, 5ul>{char [5]{(char)82, (char)101, (char)97, (char)108}}>::v:
        .string "Real"
Wrapper<std::array<char, 2ul>{char [2]{(char)65}}>::v:
        .string "A"
Wrapper<std::array<char, 3ul>{char [3]{(char)73, (char)115}}>::v:
        .string "Is"
Wrapper<std::array<char, 5ul>{char [5]{(char)84, (char)104, (char)105, (char)115}}>::v:
        .string "This"

This means it doesn't store the template's pretty function name in the binary, only the enumeration value as string. It is even better than a switch based version, since it's making a map for the enumeration instead of a jump table like a switch based version.
The basic idea for this code (and why it's so short: because it's dumb), is to create an array of const char * pointers pointing to the enumeration string for the given index, a bit like:
const char * fromEnum(Enum v) 
{
   static const char * array[] = { "This", "", "Is", "A", "", "Sparse", "Enum" }; 
   return array[(int)v];
}

That's what enum_value_name is doing.
In order to get it done automagically, we simply create a dumbly large array (in the example code above, of 128 items) and iterate it one by one filling in the enum textual value.
In order to get the textual value, we rely on the fact that we instantiate a template function for this value and the compiler is kind enough to replace the index by enum value when one exists. So enum_value_name_impl does this, it get the current pretty function name, like enum_value_name_implXXX [with enm = Enum, auto $ = Enum::Value] for enumeration value that exists and ... auto $ = (Enum)23] for those who don't. It then a matter of compile time string parsing to extract only the interesting part.
Obviously there are downside:

The search for value is linear at compile time. There's no way for the compiler to know that it has seen the last value in the enumeration. In the example code it's limited to 128 value in the range variable. Without reflection, it won't be possible to improve on this. You can increase this value, but the compile time will increase as much.
Similarly, it won't search negative enum value. This can easily be fixed when creating the map, but again, increasing the compile time.
The C++ standard doesn't specify how the pretty function name should be generated (in source_location or worse, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ macro). So the above code will work with G++ and Clang but not other compiler. Fix to your need.

If you know your enum aren't sparse, you can limit the compile time to the only linear range of your enum's value, simply by running a 2 step process: find the range first (similar to enum_value_name_impl, simply search for :: after $, if it's there, the value exists in the enum), then limit the array to that range instead of 128 values like in the example code.
See example code here for contiguous enum, where compile time is reduced to the minimum.
